# Is the use of "je" to represent "each" used in everyday speech?

Tags: word-usage

I've noticed constructs in books using "je" to represent "each" but is that common usage in everyday speech? I haven't heard my teachers use it much but maybe they're saying it too fast for me to pick up.

For example:

> He gave us ten euros each.
>   Er hat uns je zehn Euro gegeben.

Or is there another way to phrase such a sentence?

Comment: That's absolutely common. The alternative would be `Er hat jedem von uns zehn Euro gegeben`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Je* is short for *jeweils* here.

> Er hat uns je zehn Euro gegeben.

This is indeed very common. Other options:

> Er hat uns jeweils zehn Euro gegeben.
>
> Er hat jedem von uns zehn Euro gegeben.

Comment: In diesem Kontext **können** "je" und "jeweils" synonym sein, dennoch verstehe ich den Satz mit "jeweils" anders. Meiner Ansicht nach bedeutet "jeweils" hier "jedes Mal".

Comment: mir ist nichts bekannt, wo "je" überhaupt je "jedes Mal" bedeutet..?

Comment: @christian.s Das hat auch niemand behauptet.

Comment: Entschuldige, dann habe ich Dich falsch verstanden. Was meinst Du genau ?

Comment: @christian.s Erstmal bitte mich mit @ taggen, sonst lese ich es nur per Zufall. Zweitens, in DIESEM Kontext kann "je" und "jeweils" das gleiche bedeuten, nämlich dir und mir. Aber "jeweils" (nicht je) verstehe ich in diesem Kontext eher als "jedes Mal".

Comment: @Em1 Hast du Beispiele wo das so tatsächlich verwendet wird? Ohne vorherige Zeitangabe würde ich das niemals als "jedes Mal" verstehen.

Comment: @Em1 ich denke, dass deine Auslegung falsch ist. "Jeweils" hat keine Beziehung zu Zeit per se. Vielleicht sind Konstruktionen moeglich, in denen die Bedeutung als "each" sich auf vorher benannte zeitliche Wiederholungen beziehen kann, aber das ist eine Ausnahme, die auch in vorhergehenden Saetzen klar gemacht werden muss. Die primaere Bedeutung von "jeweils" ist nicht mit Zeit oder zeitlicher Wiederholung verbunden, und es gibt keinen Grund, es in diesem Satz so auszulegen.

Comment: @schlingel "Ich brachte ihm alle zwei Tage eine Milch, er gab mir jeweils einen Drops dafür."

Comment: @schlingel - npst hat also schon ein gutes Beispiel geliefert. Natürlich wird aus dem Kontext (fast) immer klar, um welches *jeweils* es sich handelt. Ich persönlich würde aber im obigen Kontext unter allen Alternativen 'jeweils' am wenigsten verwenden, um "jedem von uns" auszudrücken. Daher kommt's wohl, dass ich diese Verwendung dann 'zeitlich' interpretiere, weil sie *mir* sonst unnatürlich vorkommt. Das fällt dann wohl unter Idiolekt.

Comment: @rumtscho Das ist so nicht ganz richtig. Schlag das Wort mal in Wiktionary, Duden, DWDS nach. Es hat im wesentlichen zwei Bedeutugen, eine von denen "immer wieder" bedeutet. Das ist für mich zeitlich.

Comment: @Em1 `jeweils` bezieht sich relativ häufig auf Zeiten, sodass es „immer wieder“ bedeutet. Deswegen findet es sich vermutlich auch gesondert in den Wörterbüchern. An sich hat es aber keinen zeitlichen Bezug. Sofern die Aussage des OP nicht in einem zeitlichen Kontext steht, der eine zeitliche Wiederholung ermöglicht, hat das `jeweils` keine zeitliche Bedeutung.

Comment: @npst Ein besseres Beispiel ist: „Ich brachte ihm jeden Tag drei Eimer Milch. Er gab mir je/jeweils einen Schinken dafür.“ Mit `je` bekomme ich jeden Tag drei Schinken. Mit `jeweils` ist unklar ob ich jeden Tag einen oder drei Schinken bekomme.